# The meaning of this sentence

Tags: meaning, word-choice

"A love of the outdoors runs in the family." I don't know which meaning of "run " I should choose. Please help me explain the meaning of this sentence.

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+in+the+family

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **[Runs in](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english-thesaurus/run#run__56)** - be common in, be inherent in
>
> [ODO]